# Android Gridview with ImageButtons and TextViews. Items in gridview not lining up

Tags: android, gridview, textview, android-imagebutton

I've got a view that has a GridView with Image Buttons and Textviews but whenever the textviews that are multi line the items are not lining up as shown below.  I could set the TextView as

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

But I prefer not to.

[image]

GridView code :

```
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Template for ImageButton and TextView called by BaseAdapter :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/MainMenuImageButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MainMenuTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="trebuchet"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you have a suggestion I'd appreciate it.  Thank you.

Comment: I would add android:layout_alignParentTop="true" to your LinearLayout and if it doesnt work then add it to the imageview too

Comment: I'd already tried both of those didn't work.

Comment: I even tried setting the bottom margin of the text view and unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Dont see a problem.. its fine when I run this code..

Comment: Ideally it should be fine.  Don't understand why it's happening.  It only happens with Text that is word wrapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/MainMenuImageButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MainMenuTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="trebuchet"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:lines="2"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set textviews layout width as wrap content,set gravity as centre and also set android:singleLine="false".You'd get as you have expected.Try the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/MainMenuImageButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/MainMenuTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="trebuchet"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Initially it looks correct but when you scroll down the menu and back up it does the same thing.